# Insert new sheet using sheet template is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet names in column A of the active sheet.

I am trying to get each new tab to be a duplicate of my `Template` tab, but they are just blank.

Here is the code:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function makeTabs(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i = 1; i < last ; i++){
    var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();
    var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName,{template: templateSheet});
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell why created sheets are not based on template?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works  correctly here.

Comment: Arielle please let me know if my solution worked for you! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Here is what you are looking for:

```
function copySheets() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const last = sheet.getLastRow();
  const template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  const sh_names = sheet.getRange('A2:A'+last).getValues().flat([1]);
 
  sh_names.forEach((name)=>{            
  const copy=template.copyTo(ss);
  copy.setName(name);        
  })
}
```

### Output:

[image: example]

### Explanation:

I am using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the list of the names in **column A** of the active sheet. For each name, I am creating a copy of the template with this code:

```
const copy=template.copyTo(ss);
copy.setName(name);
```

Please keep in mind that you need to run this function when you have **selected** the active sheet (see my screenshot); the sheet that contains the name of the sheets you want to create. That is the reason I believe it is safer to get a sheet **based on its name** to be sure that you are getting the right input:

```
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

Obviously, you can't run this function more than once; it will output an error that sheets with these sheet names already exist.

Last but not least, all the duplicate sheets will have exactly the same **content** and **format** of **Template** sheet. I assume based on your question that this is your goal.

Comment: yes, this worked! Thank you for explaining this to me and helping to solve my problem!